# Modifying field values to struct pointers in Go

Tags: pointers, go, struct, mutators

New to Golang and trying to understand a code snippet I ran across. In the blog I was reading, they define a `Vertex` struct like so:

```
type Vertex struct {
  X int
  Y int
}
```

And then show an example of how to create a new instance of it and modify one of its fields:

```
v1 := Vertex{1,2}
v1.X = 3
```

However they they show an example of how to create a *pointer* to an instance of this struct and modify one of its fields:

```
v2 := &Vertex{3,4}
v2.X = 3
```

This has me a little confused. To me, the statement `v2 := &Vertex{3,4}` translates to: "*`v2` is a pointer to a new `Vertex{3,4}` instance*". If that's true, then if `v2` is a *pointer* to a `Vertex` struct, and not a `Vertex` struct itself, then how can we invoke `v2.X` on it (it's a pointer!!!)?

Comment: The compiler (or is it the runtime? i forget) dereferences the pointer automatically. So `v2.X` becomes `(*v2).X`.

Comment: ... for more info see: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors ... *"As an exception, if the type of x is a defined pointer type and (*x).f is a valid selector expression denoting a field (but not a method), x.f is **shorthand** for (*x).f. "*

Comment: C use `->` for this but a simple `.` is enough in Go so there was no need for an extra symbol.

Comment: I think this question has value for people new to Go. For a person to get to "Selectors" while searching for an answer to this problem is not easy since one would mostly search for concepts like type promotion or automatic dereference, etc. Given how the Go language is documented (pretty much the grammar rules used by the compiler i.e. one more thing to learn to read and understand other than the language), this is not out of question to be something a new language learner to be confused about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the struct fields using a pointer, you don't need dereferencing explicitly.

That's why `v2.X` is same as `(*v2).X`

Find more details [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors)